# Mark date by column contents in pandas (vectorized)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have data of the following form:

```
     JournalInformation                      Month
Dec. American Journal of Science
Molecular Methods. Aug DOI: 10101
Science Journal Jun.
Dec. Cognitive Science weekly
```

Goal:

```
     JournalInformation                      Month
Dec. American Journal of Science               12
Molecular Methods. Aug DOI: 10101               8
Science Journal Jun.                           6
Dec. Cognitive Science weekly                  12
```

---

I have millions of rows, so the solution needs to be fast.

I've found that `df.JournalInformation.apply(set("Dec").issubset)`
is very fast way of obtaining a list of booleans...However,
as pandas does not seem happy with any sort of multi index assignment, it's not obvious to me how to operationalize that boolean information (other than creating 12 columns...and that's ugly).

---

Months dict:

```
months_of_year = {  "Jan" : 1
                  , "Feb" : 2
                  , "Mar" : 3
                  , "Apr" : 4
                  , "May" : 5
                  , "Jun" : 6
                  , "Jul" : 7
                  , "Aug" : 8
                  , "Sept": 9
                  , "Oct" : 10
                  , "Nov" : 11
                  , "Dec" : 12
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.extract` and `map`

```
regex = r'({})'.format('|'.join(months_of_year.keys()))
df.JournalInformation.str.extract(regex, expand=False).map(months_of_year)
```

#### Explanation

```
print regex

(Feb|Aug|Jan|Dec|Sept|Oct|Mar|May|Jun|Jul|Apr|Nov)
```

When `regex` is used in `extract`, it will pull out the first sub string that matches a key in the months dictionary.  Then `map` will get the matching value from the dictionary.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is an amazing answer. I have over 12 million rows and this solution returned just as fast as all the other other (far simpler) vectorized string operation I've been doing. Thank you.